# Is there a human-friendly version of the Pumping-Lemma?

Tags: pumping-lemma

I found this on Wikipedia and I'm confused by the parenthesis in the notation not that it doesn't make sense to me but is there a more natural human version? And im generally confused about all the different notations surrounding logic and quantifier.

$(\forall L \subseteq \Sigma^*)(regular(l)\Rightarrow((\exists p\geq1)((\forall w\in L)$
$((|w|\geq p)\Rightarrow((\exists x,y,z\in \Sigma^\ast )(w = xyz \land(|y|\geq 1\land|xy|\leq p \land(\forall n\geq 0)(xy^nz\in L))))))))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the way the lemma is written is confusing, a more *friendly way* to write the lemma is as follows (I have added an intuitive explanation for the conditions appearing in the lemma, hoping that it is more *human readable* now):

**The Pumping Lemma:** for every regular language $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$, there is a positive pumping constant $p$ such that for every word $w\in L$ with $|w|\geq p$ (that is, for every *long enough* word in the language $L$ ), the following holds. There exists a partition of $w$ into three words over $\Sigma$, $w = xyz$,  such that:

1. $|xy|\leq p$ (that is, $y$ lies in the prefix of length $p$ of $w$).
2. $|y| > 0$ (that is, $y$ is nonempty).
3. $xy^iz\in L$, for every $i\geq 0$ (that is, if you take the word $w$ and pump the infix $y$ in $w$, $i$ times, the word $w$ remains in the language $L$).